# Logparser and IIS Advanced logging

Tags: logging, iis-7, logparser

I'm trying to parse IIS logs with a extra field enabled, to achieve it I use a TSV file. My problem is when I use a TSV to define the fields, the fields seems like they loose the data type. For example if i use SC-status in where clause I have to use quotes (sc-status = '500') instead sc-status  = 500, and same with date and time fields. any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - how are you using a TSV to define the fields? And what input format are you using to parse the logs?

Comment: I'm using a text file with the header fields separated by space. Basically i'm following this article http://blogs.technet.com/b/karywa/archive/2013/06/28/log-parser-studio-and-iis-advanced-logging.aspx

Comment: And you're specifying that file with the -iHeaderFile option?